# Set minimum sitewide with css/zurb-foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

On one of my sites I use `ZURB foundation` for layouting as it really helpful to make the website responsive, however, I need to set to set an absolutely minimum width to be `700px`. Meaning that the browser should not do any scaling after the screen is smaller than 700px.

What is the correct way to do it?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: `body {min-width: 700px;}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small screen sizes, Foundation uses a max-width of `40em`, which is equivalent to `640px`. In the Foundation css file, you'll need to find all instances of media queries that define a `max-width` of `40em`, and change the value to `43.75em`, which translates to `700px`. To maintain consistency, I would suggest sticking to using `em`.

The "medium" media queries kick in when the window width is greater than or equal to `40.0625em (641px)`, so you'll have to change these to `43.813em (701px)`.

Here's an interesting article that explains why Foundation uses `em` and why it's a good idea to use it in general: [Zurb `em` use](http://zurb.com/word/em-space)

Another website that allows you to convert `em` to `px` and vice-versa: [`px` to `em` conversion](http://pxtoem.com/)